# AWS pre-signed URL returns Signature mismatch on new bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Have following code to generate pre-signed URL:

```
params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_name}
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                            Params=params,
                                            ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

that works fine on old one bucket I am using for last year:

```
https://old-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_image.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIxxxxxxxxxxE%2F20210917%2Feu-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210917T210448Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=54e173601fec5f140dd901b0eae1dafbcd8d7ee8b8f311fdc1b120ca447cdd0c
```

I can paste this URL to browser and download file. File is `AWS-KMS` encrypted.

But same `AWS-KMS` encrypted file uploaded to new one created bucket returns following URL:

```
https://new-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test_image.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIxxxxxxxxxxE%2F20210917%2Feu-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210917T210500Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2313e0131d4251f9fba522fc8e9880d960f674f3449e141848bd38ca19e1b528
```

returns `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error:
`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

No any changes in source code - but just bucket name provided to `generate_presigned_url` function.

The IAM user I am providing to `boto3.client` has write/read permissions for both buckets.

Comparing properties and permissions for both buckets and for files I am requesting from buckets - everything looks the same.
`GetObject` and `PutObject` works fine for both buckets in a case of dealing with file directly. The issue is only in a case of using pre-signed URL.
So is any settings/permissions/rules/anything else need to be configured/enabled to make pre-signed URLs working with certain S3 bucket?

Comment: Can you check the encryption on the two buckets?  Are they identical?

Comment: can you check that the new bucket name does not contain a non-ascii character like "/", maybe you provided a folder path on your bucket name.